# Sync two HTTP Requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to render some elements on a page by making HTTP Requests to two API endpoints. When both calls have returned, I want to make a call to a third function.

For performance reasons, I don't want to chain the two API endpoint calls.

Here's my minimal example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get({
        url: `/api/one`,
        success: function (response) {
            callback_one(response);
        }
    });
    $.get({
        url: `/api/two`,
        success: function (response) {
            callback_two(response);
        }
    });
    // want to call callback_three() after both of the above requests have completed.
});
```

How do I do this correctly? I've read about Promises, async/await, Deferred, etc. but I'm not sure what the 2019 best-practice is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and do the following.

```
const urlsAndCallbacks = [
   { 
    url: urlOne,
    callback: callbackOne
   },
   { 
    url: urlTwo,
    callback: callbackTwo
   },
];

Promise.all(urlsAndCallbacks.map(item =>
  $.get({
    url: item.url,
    success: function (response) {
      item.callback(response);
    }
  })
))
.then(data => {
  fetchThirdUrl();
});
```

Comment: In this solution, how do I call the `callback_one` and `callback_two` functions?

Comment: `res` is not the response data in `fetch()`

Comment: Yes...precisely

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is use jQuery [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$.when($.get('/api/one'), $.get('/api/two')).done(function(res1, res2) {
  callback_one(res1);
  callback_two(res2);
  callback_three();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can call one and in a promise make a function calling the other one

Comment: please supply a code example of what you trying showcase in your answer.